# Spring WebFlux Reactive WebSocket Testing

Tags: unit-testing, websocket, spring-webflux, reactive-programming, spring-websocket

I am trying to write a test for Webflux Reactive websocket, the test is ok when the assertions fails, but when it is supposed to pass the test keeps running and nothing happens.

Here is the test in simplified version.

```
webSocketClient.execute(getUrl("/websocket"),
    session -> {
      return session.receive().map(WebSocketMessage::getPayloadAsText)
          .doOnNext(it->assertEquals("test", it)).then();
    }
).block(Duration.ofSeconds(2));
```

Tried placing the assertions in different places such as .map, .doOnNext(),.handle() but nothing changes.

If anybody can help, i would greatly appreciate it.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Only one solution I've found comes from spring framework itself:

- Entire test suite [WebSocketIntegrationTests.java](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/main/spring-webflux/src/test/java/org/springframework/web/reactive/socket/WebSocketIntegrationTests.java)
- Interesting part `private void testEcho()` [WebSocketIntegrationTests.java#L80](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/main/spring-webflux/src/test/java/org/springframework/web/reactive/socket/WebSocketIntegrationTests.java#L80)

```
    void testEcho() {
        int count = 100;
        Flux<String> input = Flux.range(1, count).map(index -> "msg-" + index);
        // 1. Declare variable outside of the handler's body
        AtomicReference<List<String>> actualRef = new AtomicReference<>(); 
        
        // 2. Make a websocket query
        this.client.execute(getUrl("/echo"), session ->
                session.send(input.map(session::textMessage))
                        .thenMany(session.receive().take(count).map(WebSocketMessage::getPayloadAsText))
                        .collectList()
                        // 3. Assign response to outer variable
                        .doOnNext(actualRef::set)
                        .then())
                .block(TIMEOUT); // be sure to really perform a query with block
        
        // 4. Make assertions on outer variable
        assertThat(actualRef.get()).isNotNull();
        assertThat(actualRef.get()).isEqualTo(input.collectList().block());
    }
```

In short:

1. You should create a variable outside of the session handler (Line 83)
2. Trick is to store result of the response in outer variable (Line 88)
3. Then perform full WebSocket query with block() (Line 84)
4. Now you can make assertions on this variable out of the session's scope (Line 91, 92)

P.s.
I'm not the StackOverlow answer professional, so any formatting help/suggestions are welcome!